# tfs assign work items to removed team member

Tags: tfs

In Azure tfs, if a team member is removed by clicking 'Remove from list', how can I get it back?
[image: here]

Comment: I have checked your question list, you ask questions but never give any feedback. Giving feedback in a timely manner helps others to help you solve your issue, and it helps others who see your issue know the latest status of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new work item (or when you change current work item) you can start to type the username and click <kbd>enter</kbd>, you will see the username and you can assign the work item to him, after one or two times the username will be appear again in the list.

Answer (score 0):

> In Azure tfs, if a team member is removed by clicking 'Remove from list', how can I get it back?

The drop down is actually a cached list of users you have assigned tasks to in the past.

So, **you just need enter their first name or email address to search him and assign to him. Next time, you will see him in the drop down list**.

Details steps:

1. When assigning a user to a task, enter their first name and click the search button. The user should be brought back by the search. Assign the user to the task.
2. Next time you go to assign a user to a task, if you click on the drop down list should now display the user as it is now cached.

Hope this helps.